# Detect leading white space - Python

Tags: python

I would like to know if the user entered a space before the number. Currently if you push space and then enter a number the program ignores the space and sees it as you just entered a number.

I tried a few methods found on this site but I must be missing something.

```
import re
while True:
        enternum=input('Enter numbers only')   
        try:
           enternum=int(enternum)
        except ValueError:
            print ('Try again')
            continue
        conv = str(enternum) # converted it so I can use some of the methods below
        if conv[0].isspace(): # I tried this it does not work
            print("leading space not allowed")
        for ind, val in enumerate(conv):           
            if (val.isspace()) == True: # I tried this it does not work
                print('leading space not allowed')
        if re.match(r"\s", conv): # I tried this it does not work (notice you must import re to try this)
            print('leading space not allowed')
        print('Total items entered', len(conv)) # this does not even recognize the leading space
        print ('valid entry')
        continue
```

Comment: When you did `int(enternum)`, you removed the leading whitespace. There's nothing left to detect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your example code is that you convert `enternum` to an integer (thus removing the spaces) before checking for spaces. If you just check `enternum[0].isspace()` *before* converting it to an integer, it will detect the space.

Don't forget to check that the user entered something instead of just pressing enter, otherwise you'll get an `IndexError` when trying to access `enternum[0]`.

```
while True:
  enternum = input('Enter numbers only')
  if not enternum:
    print('Must enter number')
    continue
  if enternum[0].isspace():
    print('leading space not allowed')
    continue
  enternum = int(enternum)
  ...
```

You didn't specify why you want to prohibit spaces specifically, so you should consider if that's what you actually want to do. Another option is using `enternum.isdecimal()` (again, before converting to int) to check if the string only contains decimal digits.